# flutter terminal is not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

i want to make apk of my flutter app. So I need to write "flutter build apk" command in terminal. but my terminal is not running any command. I am using Android Studio on Windows.

Comment: Have you added path variable for your flutter sdk package?

Comment: i don't know how to do that ?

Comment: Look at this. I think it'll help you - https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Thank you very much, I got that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this issue is probably because the environment path variable is not set in your android studio. Yes, you will have to set it manually in the terminal settings.
In you Android studio:
1. Go to Settings
2. click on tools
3. Click on terminal
4.Now if your environment variable block is empty, click on right most part of the bar and copy paste the path(...\flutter\bin) and save it.
5. Now, restart your IDE.
6. Open terminal in Android studio and enter flutter run..

it will surely work

Comment: I was facing this issue in Ubuntu 22.04, because by default sh shell was selected, when i changed to bash shell, it worked since my flutter was configured with bash shell. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution which might work. I struggled myself until i saw a solution in a tutorial video.
Search for "env" in the Windows 10 search box, select "edit environment variables for your account".
Find or create the variable "Path" under "User variables for [USERNAME]"
Add a new entry to your flutter/bin directory and restart android studio. Run the doctor, or another command, to check if it works :-)

Should work now in (almost) every terminal besides!